# How to use a shortcode of a plugin in another plugin php file

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I'm trying to implement reservation function in my web with two plugins of wordpress.

Two plugins are reservation plugin and payment plugin, respectively.

Reservation plugin has some steps for reservation, for example, selecting service, choosing the date, time, etcs.

I want to insert a "payment button" provided by payment plugin in payment step of reservation plugin.

I wrote down below code in php file(for payment step) of reservation plugin,

```
    <?php

     if ( shortcode_exists( 'payment_button' ) ) {

     echo nl2br("Payment plugin shortcode exists!\n");
     echo do_shortcode( '[payment_button]' );

    } 
     else {
      echo nl2br("No payment plugin shortcode exists!\n");
  }

 ?>
```

With the above code, "Payment plugin shortcode exists!" is printed out but I can't get payment button of payment plugin in my web.

Wordpress built-in shortcode like [gallery] has worked, which I did as a test.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[galley]' ); ?>
```

What should I check about two plugins or anything else?

Loading order of two plugins?

Enquescripts order of scripts used in two plugins?

I tried to load reservation plugin later than payment plugin, with adding the below code to main php file of reservation plugin , but this did not work.
(reference: https://gist.github.com/bappi-d-great/26808240df88dd1fc3fe)

```
    <?php
/*
*
* Use the code at the beginning of a plugin that you want to be laoded at last 
*
*/
function this_plugin_last() {
    $wp_path_to_this_file = preg_replace('/(.*)plugins\/(.*)$/', 
WP_PLUGIN_DIR."/$2", __FILE__);
    $this_plugin = plugin_basename(trim($wp_path_to_this_file));
    $active_plugins = get_option('active_plugins');
    $this_plugin_key = array_search($this_plugin, $active_plugins);
        array_splice($active_plugins, $this_plugin_key, 1);
        array_push($active_plugins, $this_plugin);
        update_option('active_plugins', $active_plugins);
}
add_action("activated_plugin", "this_plugin_last");
```

A little advice about my problem would be helpful to me.

Comment: It has to be via shortcode? Why not to execute the PHP function that the shortcode runs when it's called?

Comment: PHP function that the shortcode runs is a kind of member function of class. So, to do that, I have to make a instance of that class and call that member function. But some parameters are involved to that class and I don't know how that works... Therefore I'm trying to use a shortcode itself.

Comment: The `shortcode_exists()` function confirms the shortcode is already on the available tags, it's just the content not being rendered, probably is a matter of where you are trying to execute it. Is in a template? With your plugin you can use actions to insert content on templates or even better, define the template with your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

i change some line in your codes and it works

````
       <?php

    if ( shortcode_exists( 'community-events-7day' ) ) {

    echo ("Plugin shortcode exists!\n");
    echo do_shortcode( '[community-events-7day]' );

   } 
    else {
     echo ("No Plugin shortcode exists!\n");
 }

?>
   </div>```
````